# Program crashes on curl_easy_perform (compiled with VS 2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

It's my first time working with libcurl.
It crashes with the attached errors when it's in

```
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
string content;
string URL = "http://example.com";

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
    int res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    /*ostringstream out;
    out << res;
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    content = out.str();*/
}
curl_global_cleanup();
return 0;
}
```

> Program: d:\Visual\WebServerCURL\Debug\WebServerCURL.exe File:
> f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c Line: 1322
>
> Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Comment: Try `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());`

Comment: Potentially helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819550/debug-assertion-failed-crtisvalidheappointerpuserdata

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin (+1) Additionally, it looks like that [`curl_easy_setopt(... CURLOPT_URL ...)`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) wants a non-const pointer.

Comment: I tried with c_str() but still for some reason it fails. WebServerCURL.exe has triggered a breakpoint and same error displayed again.

Comment: Also check the return code of `curl_easy_setopt` Make sure it returns `CURLE_OK`.

Comment: I saw it did. It something related to the debugger I guess.

Comment: Make sure you do not mix debug and release builds. Is libcurl compiled in DEBUG mode?